# i3 synclient has no natural scrolling

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, i3-wm

I try to get natural scrolling with my touchpad working. Currently I am using `synclient` to set the touchpad configs. I have this in my `.i3/config`:

```
exec --no-startup-id synclient VertEdgeScroll=1 TapButton1=1 ... NaturalScrolling=1
```

Hovever this has no effect on natural scrolling. When I run `synclient` to see which configs are set than there is no entry for `NaturalScrolling`:

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 129
    RightEdge               = 3110
    TopEdge                 = 126
    BottomEdge              = 2221
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 175
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 79
    HorizScrollDelta        = 79
    VertEdgeScroll          = 1
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0500125
    TouchpadOff             = 0
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 0
    RBCornerButton          = 0
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 1
    TapButton3              = 1
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 2
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 19
    VertHysteresis          = 19
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 1619
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 1924
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Comment: Could you please add some information about your hardware? There is a wide range of touchpads, not all of which support all features or are even compatible to Synaptics. Also, the outputs of `xinput list` and `xinput list-props <TOUCHPAD_ID>` (the ID is listed in the ouput of `xinput list`) could be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this, though `synclient` has no explicit `NaturalScrolling` option, it has `VertScrollDelta` and `HorizScrollDelta`. Simply setting these to negatives values flips the scroll direction:

```
synclient VertScrollDelta=-79
synclient HorizScrollDelta=-79
```

So in your i3 config add:

```
exec synclient VertScrollDelta=-79 synclient HorizScrollDelta=-79
```